# Google Photos will not backup

Tags: wi-fi, backup, data-connection, google-photos

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 8 running Android 9 and One UI. Google Photos will not back up anything.

All I am getting as a `Getting ready to back up` and `185 items left` perpetual spinner at the top of the app. When I attempt to manually back up a single photo or a group of photos, I receive the message `Will upload when connected to Wi-Fi`.

I have unlimited data and am perfectly happy with it backing up over my cellular data connection. However, going into Settings->Back up & sync->Cellular Data Back Up, I see that **both** Photos and Videos are enabled. So it **should** be backing up over cellular data. But it's not.

What am I missing?

Comment: App up-to-date? Have you tried force closing and trying again? Have you tried rebooting the phone and trying again?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have just tried a force-stop on the app with no success. Following that, I have also just rebooted the phone and the issue persists. This has actually been a problem that I've been dealing with for probably as long as I've owned the device (which is over 1.5 years now) but has not been a high priority until recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to finally get Google Photos to back everything up. It's not a perfect solution, but it does seem to work for now.

Uninstall / Reinstall.

I just completely uninstalled the app, then immediately reinstalled it from the Google Play store. One of the first things it asked about in its "first-time setup" procedure was whether or not I wanted it to backup my files over cellular data. It defaults to "Wi-Fi only", but I changed it so it would back up on both Wi-Fi and cellular data.

After going through the rest of the "first-time setup" prompts, it began backing everything up, as well as giving me a "clean up ### MB of files" option. I chose that because, why not? I noticed that it did go ahead and back up all of my photos, but the spinner kept running at the top of the app, saying `285 items left` (I'm not sure of the exact number) and appeared to be stuck at that.

I decided to let it go and see if it would eventually get through them all anyway. Hours later, I saw that it was on `162 items left`. Finally, hours after that, I got the much-sought-after cloud-with-a-checkmark icon. It had finished backing them all up.

Perhaps it got stuck on some long video files or burst-shot photos—I don't know. In any case, I think the uninstall / reinstall procedure is what did the trick for me.

Comment: Always appreciate a user who finds an answer and explains it, instead of leaving us all hanging